# Postman Twitter API Retweet Count

Tags: twitter, postman

I want to get the number of retweets a post has. I am getting tweets in a hashtag so no user ID with me

[image].

I want to also be able to add the number of followers a user has. All this is done in Postman using Twitter API. Is there any way to do so please?